# Nesting SQL Statements to create Gridview with fields from several tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a Search page where the user will select the Community Name and upon pressing the Search button, a Gridview will populate displaying the owner name, resident name, and address of all the accounts in that Community.

I have the following tables: Communities, Addresses, Owners, Residents. Addresses has a foreign key of CommunityID. Owners and Residents each have a foreign key of AddressID.

With the SQL statement

```
SELECT 
     Addresses.AddressID 
FROM 
     Addresses 
     INNER JOIN Communities ON Addresses.CommunityID = Communities.CommunityID 
WHERE 
     Addresses.CommunityID = '1'
```

I get a proper list of appropriate AddressIDs that are from the first community. From there I want to list the owners, residents, and actual addresses that belong to each of these AddressIDs.

I feel like this should work:

```
SELECT        
     Owners.OwnLName, 
     Owners.OwnFName, 
     Residents.ResLName, 
     Residents.ResFName, 
     Addresses.Address
FROM            
     Addresses 
     INNER JOIN Owners ON Addresses.AddressID = Owners.AddressID 
     INNER JOIN Residents ON Owners.OwnerID = Residents.OwnerID 
WHERE 
     Owners.AddressID = ALL 
                        (
                           SELECT 
                               Addresses.AddressID 
                           FROM 
                               Addresses 
                               INNER JOIN Communities ON Addresses.CommunityID =Communities.CommunityID            
                               WHERE Addresses.CommunityID = '1'
                        )
```

I've messed around with this for so long and can't seem to wrap my mind around how to properly formulate this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
SELECT        
     Owners.OwnLName, 
     Owners.OwnFName, 
     Residents.ResLName, 
     Residents.ResFName, 
     Addresses.Address
FROM            
     Addresses 
     INNER JOIN Owners ON Addresses.AddressID = Owners.AddressID 
     INNER JOIN Residents ON Owners.OwnerID = Residents.OwnerID 
WHERE 
     Owners.AddressID IN 
                        (
                           SELECT 
                               Addresses.AddressID 
                           FROM 
                               Addresses 
                               INNER JOIN Communities ON Addresses.CommunityID =Communities.CommunityID            
                           WHERE Addresses.CommunityID = '1'
                        )
```

Comment: This is interesting because using this syntax, I get one result returned...where the AddressID and CommunityID happen to be 1. If I change my constraint to be where CommunityID equals any other valid CommunityID, I don't get any results. So it's reading this as if I want the specified fields only where the AddressID and CommunityID match each other..

Comment: Means you are saying that if you change WHERE Addresses.CommunityID = '1' this condition then you do not get results?

Comment: I did not see your response until now, my apologies. There was a slight mistake on my end, but your initial post did end up solving my problem. I was not aware of the use of "IN." Thank you!